# Viewing an SSRS Report in IE8. Text overlaps other rows when scrolling

Tags: reporting-services, internet-explorer-8

Header says it all really.

When viewing an SSRS report on IE8 ... if you scroll the text from one row will, randomly, overlap with other rows above or below.

Exporting it, or viewing pages where there is no scroll work fine.
[image: screenshot]

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance